# Best way to fetch remote RSS through authenticated proxy and parse it

Tags: php, proxy, rss, curl, magpie

I'm trying to get a remote RSS through proxy and parse it.

I'm using magpierss, but it doesn't allow reaching internet through a proxy (or I don't know how to do it).

I assume the option is to, first, fetch the rss with curl functions, that allows proxy authenticating, but ....

are there any class to do this in a easy way, or ... does magpie support using proxy, and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In `extlib/Snoopy.class.inc` find the following lines:

```
var $proxy_host     =   "";     // proxy host to use
var $proxy_port     =   "";     // proxy port to use
```

and set there you proxy url and port.

Comment: With Snoopy 1.2.4 you can define $proxy_user and $proxy_pass variables, which are necesary for authentication.